# wordpress - All posts wrapped in a div

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to display all posts on a webpage, each post shall be wrapped in a div of the class="post". Where do I have to add the HTML in the loop?

PHP

```
<?php
 query_posts('cat=5');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

HTML

```
<div class="post"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=5');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
echo '<div class="post">';
the_content();
echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: do not mix html and php, very bad style